# Java Connecting to a MySQL database error

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have been having a bit of trouble with connecting to my database. I connect to the same database on my website and it works, so I know it's probably something to do with the path to the database in my Java code.

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://ultraboodog.com:3306/ultraboo_lr", "ultraboo_root", "password");
```

I have no clue why it isn't working, and I am getting this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'ultraboo_root'@'S010650465d6c5d19.ss.shawcable.net' (using password: YES)
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

EDIT:
I am also using the mysql-connector-java plugin to connect to the database, it is made by Oracle.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html

Comment: the exception itself says you are not allow to acces the remote database. Try to create a new user and grant all priviledges to it

Answer (score 0):

MySQL access is determined by username, source address, and password. Most hosting services restrict where the user is allowed to connect from, but allow you to add locations in their panel (like cPanel).

If the server is entirely under your control and you have direct MySQL access, the [GRANT documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) for MySQL shows how to do it, for example:

```
CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

The "localhost" part could be a hostname, IP address, or wildcard such as %.example.com or 192.168.1.%. In your case since you are connecting from a cable provider, if your IP address is reasonably stable, the most secure approach is to add your exact IP address, and when it changes (hopefully rarely), you update the MySQL permissions to match.

The security implications of allowing SQL access to the Internet is something you should not consider lightly, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'ultraboo_root'@'S010650465d6c5d19.ss.shawcable.net' (using password: YES)
```

As you have mentioned problem is with creating connection with the database itself. Statement

Try something like this:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/?user=root&password=rootpassword"); 
s = conn.createStatement();
int result = s.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE databasename");
```